# Flutter use aws_signature_v4 for ProductAPI

Tags: flutter, amazon-web-services, dart, amazon-product-api, aws-signature

I am using the [aws_signature](https://pub.dev/packages/aws_signature_v4) and want to use it to `getItems` from the [Product API](https://webservices.amazon.com/paapi5/documentation/). But I simply can not make it work...

I tried it with the following code:

```
  static Future<void> getProductFromAsin({
    required String asin,
    required AmazonProductAPIMarketplace marketPlaceDetails,
  }) async {
    // Create the signer instance with credentials.
    const signer = AWSSigV4Signer(
      credentialsProvider: AWSCredentialsProvider(
        AWSCredentials(
          Env.amazonProductApiAccessKey,
          Env.amazonProductApiSecretKey,
        ),
      ),
    );

// Specify the region for the Product Advertising API
    final region = marketPlaceDetails.region;
    final scope = AWSCredentialScope(
      region: region,
      service: const AWSService('ProductAdvertisingAPI'),
    );
    // Prepare the `getItems` request
    final request = AWSHttpRequest(
      method: AWSHttpMethod.post,
      uri: Uri.https(marketPlaceDetails.host, '/paapi5/getItems'),
      headers: const {
        AWSHeaders.target:
            'com.amazon.paapi5.v1.ProductAdvertisingAPIv1.GetItems',
        AWSHeaders.contentType: 'application/json',
      },
      body: json.encode({
        "ItemIds": [asin],
        "Resources": [
          "ItemInfo.Title",
          "Offers.Listings.Price",
          "Images.Primary.Medium" // Request medium size for the primary image
        ],
        "PartnerTag": AffiliatePartners.amazonDe.id, // Your associate tag
        "PartnerType": "Associates", // Specify the partner type
        "Marketplace": marketPlaceDetails.name,
      }).codeUnits,
    );

    // Sign and send the HTTP request
    final signedRequest = await signer.sign(
      request,
      credentialScope: scope,
    );

    final createResponse = await signedRequest.send().response;
    final createStatus = createResponse.statusCode;
    safePrint(createStatus);

    return;
  }
```

But this always prints `404`.
And when looking into the `createResponse` it says:

> Bad state: Stream had already been listend to.

What am I missing here? Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: 404 is a truly unexpected response. Using Postman I can provoke 400s and 500s, but not 404 - which after all indicates that the server doesn't even understand the URL. Have you tried the cURL command builder or scratchpad (https://webservices.amazon.com/paapi5/documentation/play-around-using-scratchpad.html) to confirm the credentials are correct? Presumably, using the scratchpad in a browser you should be able to see an XHR in developer tools and see the URL and body. Next step would be to get the Java SDK and try the samples. Run in the debugger and check the URL it produces.

Comment: Then repeat without the SDK using the sample Java code here: https://webservices.amazon.com/paapi5/documentation/without-sdk.html When that's working, go through line by line against your Dart code checking the intermediate results in the debugger.

Comment: @RichardHeap Ive tried it with the Scratchpad and everything is working perfectly fine there. I tried rewriting the example code in Flutter but same result: 404.

Comment: In the scratchpad do you see the XHR request in dev tools? Can you provide working credentials (and later change them)?

Comment: @RichardHeap I would feel very uncomfortable sharing any keys :( Do you have your own keys? Could you try the code with them?

Comment: If I had my own creds, I'd use them.